# Eclipse jsp automatic validation

Tags: eclipse

In my old Eclipse (version 3.4.2) if I wrote an error in a java fragment inside a .jsp page (example a variable that doesn't exist) I automatically and immediately saw the problem (red line under 
the word).
In Eclipse neon I have to manually validate the page (right click, validate) to obtain the same result.
Is it possible to configure the new version with the old feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to go to Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings
and set up your things here.

This feature is also included in Eclipse Neon, don't worry ;) but if you really struggle hard, I suggest an uninstall/reinstall